# How to measure performance testing of Mobile app

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, testing, automated-tests

I have developed an app which is having lots of user traffic. But the problem occurs when number of users load app data and an API is triggered for different customer in same time then for some customer response is coming but for others it is not coming which failing my app.

So i want to know is their any open source tool through which i can test server load from api side.

Any help would be appreciated deeply.

Answer (score 0):

Apache JMeter which is testing tool for load test

https://jmeter.apache.org/